# Invalid ICU message. Missing '}' | Angular Material drag & drop

Tags: angular

I wanted to try using material drag & drop in my angular app but a component containing only this code literally copied from https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

```
<div cdkDropList cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    @for (tok of sentTokens; track tok) {
    <div class="example-box" cdkDrag>{{tok}}</div>
    }
</div>
```

causes me these errors even though I don't see any unescaped brackets in this code
`Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'`
`Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)`

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not running `Angular 17` so you dont have [`The new Conditional statements syntax`](https://blog.angular.io/introducing-angular-v17-4d7033312e4b) like `@for` and `@If` syntax available kindly change your code to

```
<div cdkDropList cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <ng-container *ngFor="tok of sentTokens; trackBy: tok">
        <div class="example-box" cdkDrag>{{tok}}</div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: So that's why this syntax seemed unfamiliar. I didn't realise these changes and used the wrong snippet. Now everything works.

Comment: @cptkidd yeah, I guess documentation missed it!